# matplotlib can not see the effect of setting edgecolor in plt.savefig() or plt.figure()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't figure out how to add a border around a figure, it's my understanding that this would be the figure.edgecolor parameter or savefig(edgecolor) but this does not appear to work. I'm using matplotlib 1.1.1. I would expect this code to draw a red border around the figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.savefig('test.png', edgecolor='r', facecolor='g')
```

When I look at the figure it has a green facecolor, but I don't see a red edgecolor?

The following doesn't work either:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(edgecolor='r', facecolor='g')
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

Again I see the green facecolor, but no red edgecolor. What am I doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`matplotlib.figure.Figure()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure), the figure's edge `linewidth` is set to `0.0` by default. You can visualize the `edgecolor` if you bump up this value in either of your code snippets:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(linewidth=2)
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.savefig('test.png', edgecolor='r', facecolor='g')
```

Or:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(edgecolor='r', facecolor='g', linewidth=2)
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

`linewidth=0.0` is a good default, but it should be better documented in [matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig).

Comment: Fantastic, I knew it had to be something simple that I was overlooking. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be more clearly documented. Took me a while to figure it out, particularly since `savefig()` usually overrides the color settings from `Figure()`, but apparently not the `linewidth` parameter.

Comment: Also note that you can use more colors by using `Colors()` : http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colors

Comment: For some reason, it won't show the right spline of the frame.   The others are there, but the right is missing.   Any thoughts?  thanks.